# &= operator in C# - does it work with boolean types?

Tags: c#

I have an easy question that I think I know the answer but I will ask here.

Is the code...

```
var test = true;
test = test && true;  // test remains true
test = test && false;  // test is now false
```

Equivalent to the code...

```
var test = true;
test &= true;  
test &= false;
```

&= is a bitwise operation, so I am surprised the compiler will even allow this?

Comment: For `bool` the operator is in fact not a bitwise operation, but a non-shortcircuiting logical AND: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-and-operator-

Comment: That's what led me down this path!  I had a more complex statement that used &= and I noticed the entire thing was evaluated, but I was expecting the short circuit.  Learn something new every day...

Answer (score 2):

It works, but not the same way as in first code.
The equivalent code:

```
var test = true;
test = test & true; 
test = test & false;
```

C# doesn't have &&= operator